# How to count differences derived from different tables that are greater than zero in Power BI direct query mode?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have 2 tables. Table A shows subscribed IDs and quantity of subscriptions for each ID, which can be duplicate in Table A.

Table B shows cancelled IDs and quantity of subscriptions that were cancelled for each ID, which can also be duplicate.

My goal is to sum the quantity for each unique ID in Table A and subtract the sum of the quantity for each unique ID in Table B. Then count the unique IDs with a quantity greater than zero.

Example:

[image: Example]

In this example, the result should be 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following maesure works with the sample data.

```
Distinct IDs with positive Qty =
COUNTROWS (
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                TableA,
                "totQty", CALCULATE ( SUM ( TableA[Qty] ), ALLEXCEPT ( TableA, TableA[ID] ) )
                    - CALCULATE ( SUM ( TableB[Qty] ), FILTER ( TableB, TableB[ID] = TableA[ID] ) )
            ),
            [totQty] > 0
        ),
        [ID]
    )
)
```

It works like this:

1. The ADDCOLUMNS function returns a table where a new [totQty] column is added  to TableA. in this column SUM ( TableB[Qty] ) is substracted from SUM ( TableA[Qty] ) for the ([ID]) in each row of TableA.
2. The FILTER function filters the previous table, and returns only the rows where [totQty] > 0.
3. The SUMMARIZE function returns a table that holds one columnn with the unique values of the [ID] column of the previous table.
4. The COUNTROWS function then counts the rows in this last table.